# Google App Engine: Django Load Fixtures

Tags: django, google-app-engine, django-fixtures

Normally we load fixtures, like: 
`python manage.py loaddata fixture.yaml`

but to upload to google database, it was suggested on here previously: 
`python manage.py loaddata remote fixture.yaml` , but when I try, it says `Unknown command: 'remote'`

I use Djangoo 1.4, and I have `- remote_api: on` in my app.yaml, under built-ins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. Instead of using

```
python manage.py loaddata remote fixture.yaml
```

you should type

```
python manage.py remote loaddata fixture.yaml
```